# Extracting resources containing an accent or umlaut

Tags: regex, sparql

I am looking for a specific person on dbpedia. I can get the person, and his name out via the following query.

```
select distinct * where {
    :Antonio_Damasio a dbpedia-owl:Person;
                     rdfs:label ?name
}
```

If you look at the results, you will get quite a few labels for the name with various accents (e.g. á).

[image]

I want to now reverse the query; given a label, give me the URI. You can easily get it with a variation of the following:

```
select distinct * where {
    ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person;
            rdfs:label ?name
filter(regex(?name, "^Antonio Damasio", "i"))
}
```

[image]

My problem is, in the above regular expression I omitted the letters with accent (such as á) and due to the variety of labels, I still managed to pull the resource. However, not all the resources have English labels. I want to be able to pull the resource if the user enters a label that matches a Latin alphabet. Is there a way to write a query or regular expression that given a label checks for all the variety of a letter (e.g u, ú, ü, ... ), or I just simply need to write multiple queries?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `^Ant[oóòôõ]nio Dam[aáàâã]sio` ?

Comment: I do. But I really don't know the position of the `[oóòôõ]`.

Comment: No, sadly this doesn't work. I have tried `\p{L}`, but the problem with such an approach is that you need to know the exact position, am I right?

Comment: couldn't you define a character class for each ascii character, could even use a table and then you will need to do up to 52 replacements before you can execute the regex....

Comment: Yes, this was my last resort. I was wondering if there is a magical formula that I am unaware of that could help. Thanks a lot for the help.